# Database values not changing

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a post method in my controller that looks like this and I want AvailableSeats to reduce by 1 anytime I post the form. The problem is when I run the program for the very first time and post the form, everything works perfectly but for subsequent times, the database values for the AvailableSeats doesn't reduce by 1, it just remains constant and I can't figure out why.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(BookingViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.FromLocationId == viewModel.ToLocationId)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        var busFromDb = _context.Buses.First(c=>c.Id == viewModel.BusId);
        var seatsFromDb = busFromDb.BusSeats;

        var reduce = seatsFromDb - 1;

        if (busFromDb != null)
        {
            var book = new Booking
            {
                AvailableSeats = reduce,
                FromLocationId = viewModel.FromLocationId,
                ToLocationId = viewModel.ToLocationId,
                BusId = viewModel.BusId,
                DateTime = viewModel.DateTime,
            };


            _context.Bookings.Add(book);
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

My Booking Class

```
public class Booking
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public FromLocation FromLocation { get; set; }
    public int FromLocationId { get; set; }

    public ToLocation ToLocation { get; set; }
    public int ToLocationId { get; set; }

    public Bus Bus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BusId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }
}
```

My Bus class

```
public class Bus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BusNumber { get; set; }
    public BusService BusService { get; set; }
    public int BusSeats { get; set; }
}
```

[image: BookingsDb]

[image: BusesDb]

As requested, this is my DbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Bus> Buses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FromLocation> FromLocations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ToLocation> ToLocations { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

After which I initialized it in my controller.

```
public class BookingsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public BookingsController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
```

Comment: have you tracked your actionresult? does it go through if statement?

Comment: @Valkyriee and it didn't go through the first if statement because my FromLocation isn't equal to my ToLocation so if went through the second and I saw the values change but when it saved to the database, AvailableSeats still remained constant.

Comment: @shA.t already tried that but that will make BusSeats reduce too and that's not what I want.

Comment: @AlfMoh can you try my answer please let me  know if it works . And the reason is that you are not modifying the current bus record which has same id . Please try if any issues let me know I am happy to help

Comment: can I see you DBContext Class please  and EF model classes I think we have issues in defining relationship . Please post them I will be able to help.

Comment: @AlfMoh I updated the answer and Tested on my local system by replication the same structure . Please look and let me know if it helps .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are deducting total bus seats by 1 `(24 - 1)` that always return 23 for each booking because you don't update the value `24` from Bus table, I am assuming which is total number of seats in a given bus. Rather you can count total bookings made for per bus that gives you the remaining seats.

```
int seatsFromDb = busFromDb.BusSeats; //24
int soldSeats = _context.Bookings.Count(b => b.BusId == viewModel.BusId); //2 (you need to add more filters)

int remainingSeats = seatsFromDb - (soldSeats + 1) //include the current booking (sold 3)

var book = new Booking
{
    AvailableSeats = remainingSeats,
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. And your explanation is very appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried this code with same entitty structure and now result is that on every booking the bus table BusSeats reduce to one and in Booking table availabe seats reduce to one.  I think this is want you wanted.

```
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
        -- I hardcoded id because I donthave all view model but with this i was able to achieve the result you required.
        int BusId = 1;
        var _context = new TestContext();
        var busFromDb = _context.Buses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == BusId);
        var seatsFromDb = busFromDb.BusSeats;

        var reduce = seatsFromDb - 1;

        if (busFromDb != null)
        {
            busFromDb.BusSeats = busFromDb.BusSeats - 1;
            var book = new Booking
            {
                AvailableSeats = reduce,
                BusId = BusId,
                DateTime =DateTime.Now,
                Bus = busFromDb
            };
            book.Bus = busFromDb;
            _context.Entry(busFromDb).State = EntityState.Modified;


            _context.Bookings.Add(book);
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

Below is my EF classes

```
       public class TestContext:DbContext
        {
            public TestContext()
                : base("name=TestConnection")
            {
            }
          public virtual  DbSet<Bus> Buses { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
        }

    }
    public class Booking
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Bus Bus { get; set; }  
        public int BusId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }   
    }

    public class Bus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BusNumber { get; set; }
        public int BusSeats { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: With your code, you are reducing both the BusSeats in the Bus Database table and the AvailableSeats in the Bookings database table and that isn't what I wanted. The BusSeats should remain constant whiles AvailableSeats should always reduce by 1. @Abdul's post explains that better. Anyway, thank you for your help.